# Mocha - Cannot find module './Collection/auth.js' after adding the helper file in a nested folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

My folders structure is as below:

```
App
|__ test
    |__ Helpers
        |__ Collection
            |__ auth.js
        |__ index.js
    |__ Specs
        |__ login.js
```

That's the content of the index file

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    auth: require('./Collection/auth'),
};
```

And this the content of the spec file

```
'use strict';

const { auth } = require('../Helpers');

describe('User can login successfully', () => {
    it('should return success response',async() => {
        console.log(auth);
        const response = await auth.login({
            phone: '01112223330',
            password: '123',
        });

       console.log(response.error);
    });
});
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the below error, I see this is supposed to work.

```
rror: Cannot find module './Collection/auth.js'
Require stack:
- /x-app/test/Helpers/index.js
- /x-app/test/Specs/loginSpec.js
- /x-app/node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js
- /x-app/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js
- /x-app/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/one-and-dones.js
- /x-app/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/options.js
- /x-app/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha
```

In the specs file, it is shown that the required auth has the correct value
[image]

---

Tests was working fine when the structure was

```
App
|__ test
    |__ Helpers
        |__ auth.js
        |__ index.js
    |__ Specs
        |__ login.js
```

and auth is required in index.js as `auth:require('./auth'),`

Comment: is your `Collection/auth.js` file requiring other modules?

Comment: Yes, It requires supertest @CapitanFindus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem in the docker file that wasn't detecting the code changes. It isn't a code-related problem.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve listed your folder collection above as containing "Halpers". Is that an accurate description? If it is, the error message is telling you accurately that should be "Helpers".

Comment: This was just a typo, I've updated the question.